# NHibernate with sql Server 2008 dialect don't support variable limits

Tags: sql-server-2008, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I'm fighting with a strange behavior here...
Doing an asp.net mvc3 application with NHibernate as ORM and MS SQL Server 2008 as the DB, I'm running into these exeption:

```
System.NotSupportedException: Dialect does not support variable limits.
```

The code is pretty simple, a classic pagination query:

```
public IList<Agenzia> getAllAgenzie(int maximumRows, int startRowIndex)
    {           
        using (var session = PersistenceManager.Istance.GetSession()) {
            var result = (from agenzia in session.Query<Agenzia>()
                         select agenzia)
                         .Skip(startRowIndex)
                         .Take(maximumRows)
                         .ToList();
            return result;
        }
    }
```

And here's the NHibernate configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- NHibernate Configuration -->
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory name="NHibernate.xlns">
    <property name="dialect">
      NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect
    </property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">
      NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver
    </property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>    
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Any idea what's wrong with it? I can't believe that NHibernate don't support this simple pagination...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of NHibernate are you using? (latest is 3.2)

It works without problems for me.

Also, this is redundant:

```
(from agenzia in session.Query<Agenzia>() select agenzia)
```

It's equivalent to:

```
session.Query<Agenzia>()
```

Comment: indeed it works fine... for some reason the application didn't feel the change made on the Dialect (it used to be MsSql2008Dialect) in the configuration file until I reboot Visual Studio. Once rebooted the problem disappeared

Comment: I signed you answer as the right one for the suggestion on redundancy, even if you didn't suggest a solution in the common meaning... but shame on me because there was no error :)